# Why any GWT theme is not showing in my application, only the standard theme?

Tags: gwt, themes, gwt2

I have the xml module like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='sapepass'>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization'/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.json.JSON'/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.requestfactory.RequestFactory'/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="es_CO" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="es_CO" />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/>
<entry-point class='co.ibm.spms.sap.epass.client.SAPePass' />
<inherits name="co.ibm.spms.ui.utils.Utils" />
<inherits name="eu.maydu.gwt.validation.ValidationLibrary"/>
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />
</module>
```

**Html**:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<!--                                                               -->
<!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
<!--                                                               -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="SAPePass.css">

<!--                                           -->
<!-- Any title is fine                         -->
<!--                                           -->
<title>SAP ePass</title>

<!--                                           -->
<!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
<!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
<!-- be added before this line.                -->
<!--                                           -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="sapepass/sapepass.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
```

But when I run de app, the result is that the colors correspond to Standard theme. That because the import of standrd css is after chrome css (**generated html**):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<!--                                                               -->
<!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
<!--                                                               -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="SAPePass.css">

<!--                                           -->
<!-- Any title is fine                         -->
<!--                                           -->
<title>SAP ePass</title>

<!--                                           -->
<!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
<!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
<!-- be added before this line.                -->
<!--                                           -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="sapepass/sapepass.nocache.js">   </script>
<script defer="defer">sapepass.onInjectionDone('sapepass')</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/sapepass/gwt/chrome/chrome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/sapepass/gwt/standard/standard.css">
</head>
```

What can I do?

Note:

I´m using GWT 2.1.1
Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Why are you explicitly injecting the chrome and standard css in your html? The appropriate css will automatically injected based on your module xml.

Comment: The injectios is automatic, I don't put anytjing on my html, see the question again

Comment: Sorry. No idea. In none of my apps, have I encountered this. Even if you view the source for the GWT showcase app, that too does not show this automatic injection in the html.

Comment: Can you try creating and running the default eclipse plugin project, without changing any code and see if the same is observed?For all you know, it might be because of the sequence in which you have defined the elements in your module.xml